# Trying to select element by ID using selenium and .NET but getting exception NoSuchElement due to the use of Shadowroot elements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Click here to see the image of what I'm trying to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JXt6.png)

**Below is what I have tried so far and not getting anywhere :-**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("amplify-sign-in /deep/ amplify-form-section/amplify-auth-fields /deep/ amplify-username-field /deep/ amplify-form-field /deep/ #username"));
```

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver cannot work with elements inside **shadowroot** element. I've used JavaScript to handle such elements.

```
    var clickPrintBtn = @"
        document.body
            .querySelector('print-preview-app').shadowRoot
            .querySelector('print-preview-sidebar').shadowRoot
            .querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot
            .querySelector('.action-button')
        .click();";
WebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript(clickPrintBtn);
```

In the same way you may do other manipulations with the element inside **shadowroot**.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but I was able to resolve this issue by blow method :- 

IWebElement ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);